# Google App Engine development on JDK8/JRE8 + Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, java-8, java-7

Since JDK7/JRE7 is being retired/obsoleted/unsupported, I would like to work using JDK8. I work on Linux.

Is there a way to run Eclipse, compile WARs and deploy them in some kind of a Java SE 7 "compatibility mode"? That is, Eclipse runs, and compilation, packaging, etc. all happens in SE 7, but only JDK8 is installed?

EDIT: I started a more generic question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734290/running-a-non-jre8-compatible-application-in-a-jre7-mode-on-jre8).

Comment: Hey! If I were you, I'd star this issue(https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537), and maybe post your question there as well. I know that thread is still active, so maybe someone found something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a compliance level in your project properties that will produce java7-compatible bytecode.

If you a actually want to compile against the java7 standard library then you will have to install jdk7 somewhere (just the JDK, no need for making the JRE the system default!), configure it in eclipse as alternative java  installation and configure your project to build against its standard library.

Comment: I recommend sticking to JDK7. I developed with an updated jar from maven which was compiled with JDK8. This worked fine in dev mode (on JDK8), but App Engine refused to run it, so I had to revert to an older version of the jar. Then went back do JDK7

Comment: @AlexR fyi, you can use the animal sniffer plugin to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, however, please note that the question is about >>running<< Eclipse and the toolset using only JDK8 but somehow forcing the Java environment to be JRE7. So Eclipse and all the plugins (data persistence enrichment, etc.) "sees" a JRE7, and not a JRE8. The compliance level only sets the compiler's output to be level 1.7. Or in other words: if you have plugins that are not compatible with JRE8 but JRE7, how can you "force" Eclipse to run in a compatibility mode? I tried java -version, but that does not work.

Comment: my answer contains two paragraphs, outlining both options.

Comment: Your answers are correct, but not to the original question. I don't want to install JRE7 or JDK7, they are being obsoleted. And I don't want to compile against JRE7, I want to run a JRE7 app in a JRE8 environment.

Comment: The only way to accurately force a java 7 environment is to install java7. It being obsolete should not keep you from installing it as long as you don't make it the system default (which I covered in my answer). You can selectively use it just where you need it.